# Classifying an object from an ordered sequence of spatially aligned images

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-recognition

This is about a project to count the number of tumour cells in a given 88 by 88 pixel frame. To say there is just one image is not actually accurate; there are 4 independent images of that frame i.e. the same 'situation' on the ground. All 4 of them have to be considered to count how many tumour cells there are (usually 0, sometimes 1, rarely 2).

[Here are the 4 images of a sample frame concatenated together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XueVD.png)

These images are obtained from visualising the situation through different lens (wavelengths).

I have read up on several blog articles of neural networks. However, all assume one image-one label relationship, instead of the many image-one label relationship I am working with.

Hence, I am looking for suggestions for possible tools or just the technical term related to this kind of problem so I can proceed further.

Comment: if you use imgur to upload your images they can be embedded into your question, which make it more likely that people will actually view the image

Comment: You can try just stacking the images together as input. Video related problems usually deal with multiple frames

Comment: @juvian Thank you. After some searching based on your suggestion I came across LSTMs and recurrent neural networks. Is that the kind of neural network you are talking about?

Comment: Yeah those are some, but I would try first just stacking the images. Dont thin recurrent neural networks will be useful, as you need the information from all frames and its not that one depends on the other

Comment: @juvian May I know how do you suggest I stack the images? Because there are 4 frames, I cannot simply let each frame take 1 colour channel (r,g or b). Also, the blank frame is very pixelated and I am not sure how to preprocess it

Comment: Siamese network for example deals with 2 images as input, they go through the same model to output a feature vector, and they share weights. Here is a short [tutorial in keras](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models). A simpler option might be to just make the input 1 image with the 4 concatenated like your link, but I'm not sure if that will work well